# Pandas double quotes column name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a data to dataframe.

```
LatD    "LatM"  "LatS"  "NS"    "LonD"  "LonM"  "LonS"  "EW"    "City"        "State"
41        5      59     "N"      80      39      0      "W"     "Youngstown"   OH
42        52     48     "N"      97      23      23     "W"     "Yankton"      SD
46        35     59     "N"      120     30      36     "W"     "Yakima"       WA
42        16     12     "N"      71      48      0      "W"     "Worcester"    MA
```

This is my data frame, and I'm trying this to import the data

```
data = {
    'LatD' : 20,
    '"LatM"' : 30,
    '"Lats"' : 20,
    '"NS"' : '"NS"',
    '"LonD"' : 50,
    '"LonM"' : 20,
    '"Lons:' : 30,
    '"EW"' : '"W"',
    '"City"' : '"Los Angeles"',
    '"State"' : 'CA'

}

citiesDataFrame = citiesDataFrame.append(data,ignore_index=True)
```

but it just adding LatD correctly then addin new columns named as my df columns

```
LatD   "LatM"   "LatS"  "NS"  ...  "LonM"  "LonS:  "NS" "State"
 41      5.0     59.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 42     52.0     48.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 46     35.0     59.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 42     16.0     12.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 43     37.0     48.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
..    ...      ...      ...   ...  ...     ...     ...   ...     ...
 50     25.0     11.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 40     10.0     48.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 40     19.0     48.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 41      9.0     35.0   "N"  ...     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN
 20      NaN      NaN   NaN  ...    20.0    30.0  "NS"      CA
```

Comment: Are these lines correct? ```'"Lons:' : 30,``` ```'LatD' : 20,```

Comment: has to be LonS but it doesnt matter still add new colomn

Comment: also yes they gave me these excel im not sure is it right or not but im trying to fix it

Comment: i try to print column names and i saw a space before double quotes and update my code with it

Comment: My guess would be that the problem is with the combinations of single and double quotes. E.g. you have column `LonM` in your dataframe, but you're trying to add `"LonM"` to it. The double quotes are treated like any other character, so it's a new column name.